# How to Deploy a Spring managed JPA application on JBoss 6.3 EAP

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jboss

I have a java web application. This application uses JPA for persistence. The persistence is managed by spring. This application can easily be deployed on `Tomcat`, just drop the `war` file in `webapps`. But deploying this application in `JBoss` became a nightmare to me for several days. I couldn't find an appropriate post on this site to solve the issue hence this post.

Comment: is it showing some error or you just don't know where to deploy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First and foremost, you need to configure a datasource (I used mysql database). My JBoss was installed under `C:\jboss-eap-6.3\` and I used windows operating system.
Steps:
1.  Create a directory structure `com\mysql\main` under `C:\jboss-eap-6.3\modules`. You will end up with   `C:\jboss-eap-6.3\modules\com\mysql\main` directory structure.
2. Create an `xml` file `module.xml` in this `main` directory. Additionally drop `mysql` driver jar `mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar` in the same directory. In the the end you will have `module.xml` and `mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar` in `C:\jboss-eap-6.3\modules\com\mysql\main`.
3. Copy the following `xml` content to `module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

4. Locate the file `standalone.xml` in `C:\jboss-eap-6.3\standalone\configuration` directory. Open this file with your favorite text editor. Locate the `datasource` subsystem i.e. this line `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.2">`. Add the `xml` fragment below under the `drivers` element.

```
<driver name="mysqlDriver" module="com.mysql">
    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```

Add the `xml` fragment below under `datasources` element:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MYSQLDATASOURCE" pool-name="MYSQLDATASOURCE" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName</connection-url>
    <driver>mysqlDriver</driver>
    <security>
    <user-name>root</user-name>
    <password>databasepassword</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

At this point you are done with `datasource` configuration.

Next is to configure your `persistence.xml` and `applicationContext.xml`.
**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="erPU">
        <class>..</class> <!--Contains all your Entity classes-->
        <properties>            
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="application" /> 
            <property name="jboss.as.jpa.managed" value="false" /> 
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>          
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>    
</persistence>

<!--jboss.as.jpa.providerModule     is the name of the persistence provider module (default is org.hibernate). Should be hibernate3-bundled if Hibernate 3 jars are in the application archive (adapterModule and adapterClass will automatically be set for hibernate3-bundled).  Should be application, if a persistence provider is packaged with the application. -->
<!--jboss.as.jpa.managed    can be set to false to disable container managed JPA access to the persistence unit.  The default is true, which enables container managed JPA access to the persistence unit.  This is typically set to false for Seam 2.x + Spring applications. -->
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"    

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
">

    <context:annotation-config />   
    <context:component-scan base-package="..." /><!--Package base name to scan for annotations -->        

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MYSQLDATASOURCE" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>    
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="..." /><!--Packages to scan for entities--> 
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="erPU" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"/> 
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
                <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
                <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>       
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>   
</beans>
```

Note: Irrespective of the location of `persistence.xml`, you need to tell spring where the `persistence.xml` is located. The [literature below was extracted from](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Spring+applications+development+and+migration+guide)

```
Using Spring-managed persistence units

Spring applications running in JBoss AS7 may also create persistence units on their own, using the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean. This is what these applications need to consider:
Placement of the persistence unit definitions

When the application server encounters a deployment that has a file named META-INF/persistence.xml (or, for that matter, WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml), it will attempt to create a persistence unit based on what is provided in the file. In most cases, such definition files are not compliant with the Java EE requirements, mostly because required elements such as the datasource of the persistence unit are supposed to be provided by the Spring context definitions, which will fail the deployment of the persistence unit, and consequently of the entire deployment.

Spring applications can easily avoid this type of conflict, by using a feature of the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean which is designed for this purpose. Persistence unit definition files can exist in other locations than META-INF/persistence.xml and the location can be indicated through the persistenceXmlLocation property of the factory bean class.

Assuming that the persistence unit is in the META-INF/jpa-persistence.xml, the corresponding definition can be:
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"> 
       <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/jpa-persistence.xml"/> 
       <!-- other definitions -->
</bean>
```

**WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml**
Lastly, you need to create `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` under `WEB-INF`. The content of the file should be:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
       <module name="org.hibernate"/>
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

The reason for this is:

```
Since the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and the corresponding HibernateJpaVendorAdapter are based on Hibernate 3, it is required to use that version with the application. Therefore, the Hibernate 3 jars must be included in the deployment. At the same time, due the presence of @PersistenceUnit or @PersistenceContext annotations on the application classes, the application server will automatically add the 'org.hibernate' module as a dependency.

This can be avoided by instructing the server to exclude the module from the deployment's list of dependencies.
```

Finally, the JPA libraries bundled with your application must be version 3.x.